# How can I attach an object on another object?

Tags: animation, rigging, objects, armature, constraints

I'm trying to attach an object to another object.
In my scene I have an object that must follow a rig. This object should get a glare effect, which is why I can not join the object with the rig. So how can I do that?

Comment: **How can I attach an object on another object?** By [Parenting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#parenting-objects). But please take a step back and examine your question. Are there any details or explanation you might add which could make it easier to understand?

Comment: yeah that worked but when I move the rig with the bones the objects standing anyways there...    
Here is a detailed explanation of my problems. I downloaded a rigged model. Now I have to add an object to the model that moves with the model when I use the bones. I can not join the object with the model because it has to remain a separate object because I want to make a glare effect on it.

Comment: ok I got it. You must select the object, than the bones, press strg + p and select bone.

Comment: yes that worked great. thx for your help.